# application terminates after this error message in Console : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Tags: ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

```
kill
quit

The Debugger has exited with status 0.
[Session started at 2011-03-18 14:27:30 +0530.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Wed Jul 21 10:53:12 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 4478.
2011-03-18 14:27:32.460 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <MoviesListViewController: 0x5f319a0>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2011-03-18 14:27:34.400 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <Community: 0x5f37a50>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2011-03-18 14:27:45.272 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] -[TestFile <null selector>]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f38ff0
2011-03-18 14:27:45.277 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestFile <null selector>]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f38ff0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02515b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0266540e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025176ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024872b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02486e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Foundation                          0x0004221a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x024f6f73 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x024f85b4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1364
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x02454dd9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x02454350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02454271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x02d7000c GSEventRunModal + 217
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x02d700d1 GSEventRun + 115
    13  UIKit                               0x002d1af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    14  TabBarAndNav                        0x00002004 main + 102
    15  TabBarAndNav                        0x00001f95 start + 53
    16  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Comment: What is the question? Where is the code that is crashing? You need to be much more specific - we can't guess what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following lines in the console message,

```
2011-03-18 14:27:45.272 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] -[TestFile <null selector>]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f38ff0
2011-03-18 14:27:45.277 TabBarAndNav[4478:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestFile <null selector>]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f38ff0'
```

It says that your calling a selector for TestFile object.